# Is ther a way to set user input as name for 2nd level node in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an html form which sends user data to firebase db and currently looks like the image below. If I use push method to save user data the garbled unique ID is generated and if I use set then I have to enter the Node title as string, but what I intend to do is to add for example the email of the user as the node title of user so every user has his own node (name number etc under his email), not sure if it is possible, not able to find any way of doing it, nothing in firebase docs either.

Any ideas ?

```
var registration = firebase.database().ref("REGISTRATION")

function dbsave(){
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var genval = $("#gender").val();
  var date = $("#date").val();
  var ContactNumber = $("#phone").val();
  var school = $("#school").val();
  var clas = $("#clas").val();
  var classname = $("#classname").val();

registration.push({
    Email: email,
    Name: name,
    Password: password,
    Gender: genval,
    Birthday: date,
    ContactNumber: phone,
    State: state,
    School: school,
    Class: clas
})
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQogs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to use the email address as a key, especially since it is possible to merge accounts if the user created more than one with the same email address.

Use that garbled key as you call it. That's why it is there for you. Under that you have your properties email, displayName, etc.

Comment: I intend to disallow creation of same email address, what I intend to do is to check if an email key/value already exists, if yes then the user will not be able t create a new account, thats the idea..

Comment: The Firebase authentication subsystem does that for you. It's baked in. There's even a toggle on the web ui to disallow multiple acct's w same email i think. Try it. https://github.com/rhroyston/firebase-v4-auth

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, however out of curiosity is it even possible to do what I am seeking, it makes my work more convenient and in order..

Comment: Get the db structure right from the start or your gonna have to work 3x to re-do it later. They tell you how to start out right. See [Structure Your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) You want a top-level `users` node to push into each child is a key whose child is name, address, favorite color, etc.